# How do I assert element events using Jest and React Testing Library?

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component library that I'm adding tests to. I want to ensure correct events are passed into handlers. eg. A Button component passes the entire event object and not just an event target value. How can I assert this correctly?

Currently I pass a mock function and set a local var and then assert that it's true.
My issue with this solution is I have a local variable "target" in every test that could be manipulated. Preferably I would like something more idiomatic. For example using the `toHaveBeenCalledWith` assertion.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-haze-5z4k86?file=/src/test.js

Answer (score 0):

From your description and code attached, in my opinion I don't think you need to have any other function call tests for this component. Asserting `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` after a click or after a certain keyboard event should be sufficient. My reason for this is that your component is agnostic to logic (which is a good thing when it comes to components provided by a component library) so it shouldn't care what is the function that it is being passed to or what it being called with. You only need to demonstrate that the function the consumer of this component decided to pass to it, has been called successfully.

It is up to the consumer of that component to write an integration/implementation test for the component where they use it